# Please give very simple basic POST command code for android studio

Tags: android, post, file-upload, get, http-post

I want to send a simple POST command to upload files. How can I write the code in android developer? Code should give the following POST request

```
POST /macros/s/AqtUErjtk/postform?no&func=uploadFiles HTTP/1.1
Host: xyz.website.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------236532717524914
Content-Length: 337
```

Cookie:

```
NID=106=gWQeUVIa2phdDJeXYdRFSPTnsklPrFVRwphw3G685QYZlDiZz7NK5PoJVEd1FYL6IqYoJ9fEtVHf0sKBIHq1wD1xr
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1


-----------------------------236532717524914
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_1_myFile"; filename="textfile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Here is the text file content yoyoyoyoyoy
-----------------------------236532717524914--

Comment: See if this link can help you: https://community.particle.io/t/example-android-application-post-get/9355

Comment: Did you have success? :)

Answer (score 0):

In the following link you will see an example in which a POST is made:

https://community.particle.io/t/example-android-application-post-get/9355

This is the exact code extracted from the link above:

```
class PostClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public String doInBackground(String... IO) {

            // Predefine variables
            String io = new String(IO[0]);
            URL url;

            try {
                // Stuff variables
                url = new URL("https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/YOURCOREID/SCL/");
                String param = "access_token=YOURACCESSTOKEN&params=d7,"+io;
                Log.d(TAG, "param:" + param);

                // Open a connection using HttpURLConnection
                HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                con.setReadTimeout(7000);
                con.setConnectTimeout(7000);
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                // Send
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                out.print(param);
                out.close();

                con.connect();

                BufferedReader in = null;
                if (con.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
                    Log.d(TAG, "!=200: " + in);
                } else {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    Log.d(TAG, "POST request send successful: " + in);
                };


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            // Set null and we´e good to go
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.